# Tidying up questions in a particular subject area

Tags: discussion

This question is directed mainly at the mods, but, of course anyone can express an opinion.

Because of the work of our phantom editor, a number of old questions recently re-emerged, some of which were in an area of interest to me (the initiation of proteins synthesis). I did some work editing a question with multiple parts (splitting off and answering a part that hadn't been answered) and I thought it might be useful if each question in this group was provided with *a short list of related but different questions*. The idea would be to help users find more info on specific aspects of the subject, and this would be consistent with the aim of SE Biology to create a sort of reference facility.

My question is really how best to go about this (if at all). One possibility would be to put a footnote to every question listing related questions, and even editing the titles a little. Of course, some posters might object, although most would be long gone. Alternatively I could do it on my own answers (as I had starting doing), but I haven’t answered all relevant questions as some had satisfactory answers before I muscled in.

Comment: I personally don't see any reason why to *not* do that. It sounds like a great idea. Given your knowledge in the field I bet the initiative is in good hands. But that's just my 2 cents.

Comment: Some of this is already done by SE in terms of the related questions on the right, and linking questions via tags. Is it possible that simply renaming some of these questions to have excellent informative titles and appropriate tags would do the trick?